# How can I count number of looping cycles in number factorization

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop

I want to factor a number and count the number of times each prime number is multiplied to get the desired one. For example `200=2*2*2*5*5` which would give me `[[2,3],[5,2]`.

This is what I wrote:

```py
def factor(N):
    f = []
    k = 2
    c = 0
    while k <= N:
        if N % k == 0:
            while N % k == 0:
                b = N / k
                N = b
                c += 1
            f.append([k, c])
        else:
            k += 1
    return f
    
    
 n = factor(200)
 print(n)
```

output:

```
 [[2, 3], [5, 5]]
```

expected output:

```
 [[2, 3], [5, 2]]                  # come from 200 = 2x2x2x5x5
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the counter on the first loop, like on the code below.

```
def factor(N):
    f = []
    k = 2

    while k <= N:
        c = 0
        if N % k == 0:
            while N % k == 0:
                b = N/k
                N = b
                c += 1
            f.append([k, c])
        else:
            k += 1
    return f

n = factor(200)
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your count (`c`) after adding to the resulting array.

You should also stop the loop when your factor reaches the square root of the number (or the square of the factor is higher than the number):

Here's a generator version of the prime factor function that does not need to store the prime factors in memory:

```
def primeFactors(N):
    prime = 2
    while N >= prime * prime:
        power = 0
        while N % prime == 0:
            power += 1
            N //= prime
        if power: yield (prime,power)
        prime += 1 + (prime&1)
    if N>1: yield (N,1)


print(*primeFactors(200))             # (2, 3) (25, 1)
print(*primeFactors(360324))          # (2, 2) (3, 2) (10009, 1)
print(*primeFactors(2485335125))      # (5, 3) (7, 6) (13, 2)
print(*primeFactors(882635521699397)) # (149, 2) (3413, 3)
print(*primeFactors(5196703574764221304787))   # (4733, 1) (101611, 1) (119923, 1) (90104863, 1)
print(*primeFactors(13059300506111507933977974861361)) # (17, 4) (5521, 7)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def factor(N):
f = []
k = 2

while k <= N:
    c = 0
    if N%k == 0:
        while N%k == 0:
            b = N/k
            N = b
            c += 1
        f.append([k, c])
    else:
        k += 1
        c = 0 **#You have to reset the counter here..**
return f

n = factor(200)
print(n)
```

Comment: This is wrong. The counter is already reseted to 0 on each iteration of the first while....